# How to check and get new JSON everytime the feed is updated?

Tags: c#, .net, json, vb.net

Using this as example (lets say that its updated every 10 mins), how do I know that the feed has new entries without getting al the data again? Also, how do I get only the latest update (the last object so I can add it to the list that I already have).

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If the document is updated every ten minutes, you will have to get the entire document and convert the JSON to a C# object via deserialization.  After that, you can choose (via javascript's setInterval for every 10 minutes) to call an AJAX method that will return only a single (the latest) row from the C# deserialized object.

Comment: I take it that you do not have access to change how the base API works.  If all the API does is dump a big list, there's nothing else you can do but parse that big list.

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is to get all the list every 10 mins, just the latest updates, is that possible? If no I will just update it every certain time. The problem is that I would like to recieve the data as soon as its posted on the JSON feed, that would be 1 min updates, isn't it gonna be too much?.

Comment: Hopefully that big list has something of the nature of a timestamp on the items.  That would make it easier.

Comment: One alternative:  Create a separate web service to call and deserialize the JSON file at a set interval, then save the results to the database.  Then, you can simply call your own database for the latest record.  This way, you process the document once, and then deliver to your users in a short, simple call to your database, rather than parsing the file everytime your user's load the page.

Answer (score 0):

I glanced over some of the feeds exposed in their API,  and I'd suggest using one of the more granular time-frame feeds to check for updates.

For example,  http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson
updates every minute,  and has the last hour's updates.   Just get that feed every minute, since it's only a tiny fraction of the size (5kb vs 4.9MB), and compare against the last few items you got last time.

(I did a quick check against some IDs in both the all_month list and the all_hour list,  the IDs do match up correctly)